# Given a list of numbers in a field, how to sum them and print them in an (n)awk script?

Tags: bash, nawk

Given this list of names and numbers:

```
Kirilienko:47
James:23 
Bryant:24
Durant:35
Griffin:32
```

How would I find sum the numbers in the second field and print them in an awk **script**, in the sentence:

`print "The total number of these five players is [161]."`

I've done a bit of research and saw the general way to sum a column was with `awk {sum += $3} END{print sum}`. I've tried to implement this in my script, only to return sum = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the field separator as `:`, and get the sum of the second field. In the `END` block print the sum with desired text:

```
awk -F: '{sum+=$2} END{print "The total number of these five players is ["sum"]."}' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
Kirilienko:47
James:23 
Bryant:24
Durant:35
Griffin:32

% awk -F: '{sum+=$2} END{print "The total number of these five players is ["sum"]."}' file.txt
The total number of these five players is [161].
```

Comment: Thanks! Since I am using a script, though, do I separate the {sum += 2} and the END{print} blocks?

Comment: @KevinMoy A shell script or `awk` script?

Comment: It would be a shell script, apologies. The script is appended with `.script`

Answer (score 0):

While the question specifies `awk`, it never hurts to have other options. In this particular case you can also do this purely in Bash:

```
sum=0
while read num
do 
    num="${num#*:}"
    sum=$(( $num + $sum ))
done < file.txt
echo "The total number of these five players is $sum"
```

Output:

```
The total number of these five players is 161
```